# How to find the rate at which water can pass through a semipermeable membrane that allows particles of size lesser than 0.5 mm?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, osmosis

I was wondering what would be the rate at which water would cross a semipermeable membrane that allows particles of size greater than 0.5 mm. Knowing that size of water molecules is 2.75 angstroms which is much smaller compared to the sieve, will the membrane allow water to pass through it without any effort? Or, I am missing some concepts involved?

Also without loss of generality, it can be assumed that on one side it is water containing some impurities whose size can be greater than 0.5 mm while the other side do not contain any impurities.

Additionally, what is the mathematical approach to finding the approximate rate involved?

Comment: Do you mean _particles of size **less** than 0.5 mm_? i.e. the holes in the membrane are 0.5mm?

Comment: @JohnRennie the holes of membrane are 0.5 mm hence ensuring that only particles of size less than 0.5 mm would pass the membrane.

Comment: @JohnRennie I am sorry it is _particles of size **greater** than 0.5 mm_. Thanks.